# How Do I Set My Invisibility in GMOD Server WIth a Mod

Tags: mods, garrys-mod

I can set my invisibility but people can still see the weapon I am holding. The only item they cant see me hold is the tool-gun. Is it possible to set myself completely invisible with ULX or with some other mod.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this will help: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1839647

Happy gaming!